# working with Strings - how can I make "small numbers" in the upper part like in real books - is it possible?

Tags: java, android, string, spanned

Sorry , my English is not enough to explain clearly what I want, maybe that's why I can't find answer in the Google.

When you use real book - sometimes you have some text there that needs an explanation and after that text you have "*" sign and an explanation at the bottom of the page under a line.

And sometimes it's not a "*", it's a small number at the top of last word. Like "1" , "2" ,etc, and then same explanation at the bottom of the page under a line.

What I need to know - is there any instrument in java/Android SDK to have this numbers to be small and at the top in TextView?

Like, maybe Spanned Strings can do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to produce such a `Spanned` is with the Html utility class:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("book<sup>1</sup>"));
```

Comment: Thanx alot !That's too bad for me to not know Html :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SubscriptSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SubscriptSpan.html) or [SuperscriptSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/SuperscriptSpan.html) within a [SpannableString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/SpannableString.html).

Answer (score 2):

Tested Demo

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hi this demo test for book reading effect <sup>2</sup>"));
    }

}
```

**OutPut:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Achive this 2 Way.

1) Using SuperscriptSpan:

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString("book1");
        span.setSpan(new SuperscriptSpan(), 4, 5,
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
txt.setText(span, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

2) Using Html:

```
txt.setText(Html.fromHtml("book<sup>1</sup>"));
```